# Undoing diff put when copying lines between vimdiff windows

Tags: vim, text, diff, text-editor, vimdiff

If, at a command prompt, I run

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

I get a vim instance that has two files open side-by-side. Let's suppose that the text in the files looks like this (file1 is on the left, file2 on the right):

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║foo    │-------║
║bar    │bar    ║
║grue   │-------║
║~      │~      ║
║~      │~      ║
╚═══════╧═══════╝
```

Now suppose that my cursor is on the "f" of "foo" and that I wish to copy the first line of file1 to the first line of file2.

One way to do this is to select and yank (copy) the line with **v$ y**, and then use **Ctrl+w l** to move the cursor across to the first line of file2, and then type **p** to paste the copied line. If I do this and I then decide I didn't really want to do it after all, I can press **u** to undo the paste command I carried out in file2.

Another way to do it is to use the diff put command dp. However, if after doing this I decide I didn't mean to do it, I can't undo it simply by pressing **u** because my cursor is still in file1 and the **u** command will undo the most recent change to file1, *not* the most recent change to file2. So instead I have to use **Ctrl+w l** or **Ctrl+w w** to move the cursor to the window for file2 and *then* press **u**.

So, my question is: after I have used **dp** as above, is there any easy way for me to undo it without having to move my cursor across to the other file's window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is really no command for this but you could map your own.
Put the following in your vimrc and then use **du** to do *diff undos*.

```
nmap du :wincmd w<cr>:normal u<cr>:wincmd w<cr>
```

Comment: This could behave weird if there is more than two windows. (Just a note, nonetheless a perfect answer to the question).

Answer (score 13):

Depends how your workflow goes, but I usually use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to Obtain a diff into my file rather than <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> which Puts the diff into the other.  That way you can use <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> as usual.

Since the diff navigation commands work the same from either file, you should be good to go!

next diff: `]c`

prev diff: `[c`

Answer (score 1):

When comparing files, I like to use `vimdiff` or `vim -d`. A way of copying changes with `vimdiff` is:

```
]c               - advance to the next block with differences
[c               - reverse search for the previous block with differences
do (diff obtain) - bring changes from the other file to the current file
dp (diff put)    - send changes from the current file to the other file
```

This works like:

```
:diffget the same with do
:diffput the same with dp
```